# Realm Instances remain opened after Application was killed

Tags: android, realm

The situation is as follow, I have a lingering Realm instance that is persisting even after I am killing the application. This was found by accident, I was under the impression that all unclosed realm instances would be closed upon Application being killed (not force stop). If you can provide some insight into this issue, I would appreciate it.

I am calling Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount() to check how many realm instances are still open upon starting the application and upon closing the application. This is done before and after all realm instances within the application are closed explicitly.

Here are the device stats as well as the version of Realm I am using.

Additional Stats:
Realm version 3.1.4
Device: Nexus 6p Emulator Api 23

**Edit 1:**

Below is what I call on my login screen (before I actually open an instance), the expected result is 0. However I am getting 1 or 2 randomly, as I am still figuring out why this is happening when I close my application. I cannot provide any reason why Realm would not close when the application is killed, if you can chime in and let me know under what circumstances this behavior would occur I would appreciate it.

```
 Log.v("test","realm instance count when starting app | calling from thread " + android.os.Process.myTid() + "| count = " + RealmController.printRealmInstanceCount());
```

printRealmInstanceCount method below

```
  public static int printRealmInstanceCount(){
    try {
        int i = Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(getDefaultConfiguration(
                SceneDocApp.getUser().getUserFolderName(),
                Hex.decodeHex(SceneDocApp.getUser().getRealmDbKey().toCharArray())));
        return i;
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return -1;
}
```

The call below is used to setup the singleton and holds reference to main thread realm instance.

```
 RealmController.getInstance();
 //code for above method 
  public static RealmController getInstance() {

    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = new RealmController();

        try
        {
            Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(getDefaultConfiguration(
                    SceneDocApp.getUser().getUserFolderName(),
                    Hex.decodeHex(SceneDocApp.getUser().getRealmDbKey().toCharArray())));

            if (mRealm != null && !mRealm.isClosed())
                mRealm.close();


            mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Common.makeLog(RealmController.getInstance().getClass(), e.getMessage(), Level.ERROR);
        }

    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Clearing the task doesn't kill the process.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you kill the application, the Realm instances will be closed.  ... but if you kill the application, you can't be running `Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount`.  Please supply some code and explain what it is you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: RealmController? Is this based on Ravi Tamada's broken tutorial again?

Comment: Yeah... We still can't see the critical code: where is the variable `instance`?  Where do you call `getInstance`?  And so on.  I *GUARANTEE* that if you kill the application, all Realms are closed. s I what to know what makes you think you've killed the application!

Comment: Hi Blake, the application is not closed from code. I am manually closing it via the Overview button then swipe to close app (the Square button on Android). That should kill the application, I have tested it with a sample application. I can share code for that application. The above code is showing how I am checking the number of open realm instances, which is done on startup of our application.

Comment: Again: once the application is closed, all files are closed.  This includes any Realm files.  I think the issue is that you are finding that there is a Realm instance open before you expect it to be open.  You are calling  `printRealmInstanceCount` somewhere, and it is telling you that there is an instance open.  Please do share the application.  I think we can get to the bottom of this.